# Issues with missing collate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform the below query, but, I'm getting the error:

```
Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in add operator.
```

The SQL statement is the one below :

```
DECLARE @sql_str VARCHAR (max)
DECLARE @startdate DATE
DECLARE @enddate DATE
DECLARE @lastParsedDate datetime
DECLARE @dayOfWeek VARCHAR(10)


SELECT @lastParsedDate = last_timestamp 
FROM etl.[Heap].[ETL_LAST_PARSED_DATE]
WHERE process_name = 'xnet_etl_process_temp_get'

SET @startdate = CONVERT(date, '2021-03-01') 
print(@startdate)
SET @enddate   = CONVERT(date, '2021-08-30')
print(@enddate)

SELECT @dayOfWeek=DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(d,1,@lastParsedDate))
FROM etl1.[Heap].[ETL_LAST_PARSED_DATE]
WHERE process_name = 'xnet_etl_process_temp_get'

SET @lastParsedDate = null

SELECT @lastParsedDate = data_end_date
FROM OperatorNet.dbo.cn_weekly_temp_get where data_end_date=@enddate and domain=0

SET @startdate = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(d,1,@startdate),103))

if ((@lastParsedDate is null)AND(@dayOfWeek='Sunday')AND(@enddate<GETDATE()))
--BEGIN

/*CREATE TABLE OperatorNet.dbo.temp_get
(
    A_REC INT,
    B_REC INT,
    CALL_SOURCE INT,
    CALL_DEST INT,
    A_NUM VARCHAR(50),
    B_NUM VARCHAR(50),
    DURATION BIGINT,
    NETWORK VARCHAR(50),
    REC_TYPE INT
)*/

SET @SQL_STR = '
    SELECT
        A_REC,
        B_REC,
        CALL_SOURCE,
        CALL_DEST,
        A_NUM,
        B_NUM,
        DURATION,
        NETWORK,
        REC_TYPE
    FROM
        OPENQUERY(CDRGO_SYBASE_MEDIATION, ''
            SELECT
                a_rec,
                b_rec,
                call_source,
                call_dest,
                a_num,
                b_num,
                duration,
                network,
                rec_type
            FROM
                DE.BI_DATA
            WHERE
            ' + ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent(@startdate, @enddate, 'A') + '
                --' + ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent(@startdate, @enddate, 'A') + ' collate as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                --' + ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent(@startdate, @enddate, 'A') + '  collate as Latin1_General_CI_AS
                --'' + ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent(@startdate, @enddate, ''A'') + ''
                
        '') SV'


INSERT INTO OperatorNet.dbo.temp_get
exec(@sql_str)
```

I'm already trying to use the collate command, but, it seems that I'm not using in the right place in the right way.

I did some research but could figure out where to do the collate exactly, I'm new to the SQL Server.
Could you guys help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` it, debug it, propagate the solution. *We* can't run your SQL (we don't have any sample data, nor the definitions for things like `ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent`), so we have no idea why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working across databases is a common source of collation issues. For example, suppose I have two databases, `DB1` and `DB2`. `DB1`'s default collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, and `DB2`'s is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

If I do the following I will get a collation conflict:

```
use DB1;
go

create or alter function dbo.foo() returns varchar(10) as begin 
   return 'foo';
end
go

use DB2
go

declare @bar varchar(10) = 'bar' + DB1.dbo.foo();
```

The error is:

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in add operator.

To resolve this error, I can force the collation I want it to use for my expression:

```
set @bar = 'bar' + DB1.dbo.foo() collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

The way explicitly setting collation works in expressions can be unintuitive. For example, this would also have worked:

```
declare @bar varchar(10) = 'bar' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  + DB1.dbo.foo();
```

That's weird, I'm in `DB2`, and `DB2` already has a collation of `sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as`, so why would setting the literal `'bar'` to that make any difference? Well, because I'm being explicit.

In your code you are doing the same kind of thing as I am in my sample problem. You are declaring the variable `@SQL_STR` and assigning a value to it. You then try to append the result of `ETL1.dbo.BI_GetSybaseIQDateExtent` to that variable. That function is in a different database. It is highly likely that the database you are in, and database ETL1, have different collations.

To resolve the problem, set an explicit collation on your string concatenation, instead of inside the strings being concatenated (which is what you are doing now). To make it easier to read you can do it right up front:

```sql
SET @SQL_STR = '' collate latin1_general_ci_as + '
    SELECT
        A_REC,
        B_REC,
        CALL_SOURCE,
        -- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when your database and master database collation differs.

I have solved the issue with the below link.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/

Option#2 is useful in the above link for a change of collation in master db.